# Can the phrase "there's no such thing as..." be used in context of time?

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage

I was wondering if the idiomatic phrase can be altered as follows...

`...There's no such time as one [when/where] child rearing is easy...`

I'm also uncertain which word bracketed above is more appropriate, assuming this usage even makes any sense.

Comment: At no time is child rearing easy.

Comment: @Jim thanks for the variant, but I'm hoping to get an answer in regards to the specific verbiage.  Well, it looks like in regards to the usage at least the expression is acceptable (according to LPH's answer), which means I just need to find out which bracketed word choice is more suitable/correct.

Comment: @Arctiic: No, it's not acceptable. I am trying to work out why, and I will get back to you if I figure it out. But believe me, it is not something a native speaker would say. (And if forced to decide at gunpoint, I would use 'when'.)

Comment: There's no such time as 25-o'clock.

Comment: Google Books searches for "no such time as one in which" and "no such time as one when" turn up zero matches, suggesting that use of either phrase in published writing in English is vanishingly rare.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the sentence seems to come from the meaning of "time" - does it mean an instance? This doesn't work as rearing children is durative, or does it mean "an age/epoch/period?"

Added to this "There's" tends to be interpreted as "there is" but the reference seems as if it ought to be to the past, thus calling upon historical evidence.

I suggest

**There was never a time when** child rearing was easy.

This has the advantage of implying that there will not be such a time in the future.

This seems to be the standard version as per these snippet views from Google Books:

> *God: a Self Portrait* - Page 24 Philip McCarty 2004 *"There was never a time when you started reading;"*

> *Will Rogers* Betty Rogers 2012 *But there was never a time when Will could not stand off and take a cool, appraising look at himself.*

> *The Second Time Around* - Page 23 Chuck Dozier 2013 "*There was never a time when Cherry did not know how to get in touch with her mother at a moment's notice."*

Answer (score 0):

From this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There+is+no+such+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=16&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2CThere%20is%20no%20such%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BThere%20is%20no%20such%20thing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20is%20no%20such%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20is%20no%20such%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20is%20no%20such%20word%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20is%20no%20such%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20is%20no%20such%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20is%20no%20such%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20is%20no%20such%20danger%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20is%20no%20such%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20is%20no%20such%20fact%3B%2Cc0) you can see that the following words are used: place, word, person, man, passion, danger, name, fact. There is bound to be many others: the words figuring  in the research  are only those that are found rather often. There is no reason then to believe that "time" couldn't be used.

Here is an example with "no such time as", where time means "time period".

[Targeting Maths, Nicole Bauer - 2001 -](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7mb1pnhwO7EC&pg=PP133&dq=%22no+such+time%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSrrKEnMroAhWJCWMBHVexAt0Q6AEInAMwIw#v=onepage&q=%22no%20such%20time%22&f=false)
... in a year. p An Olympic race can be won or lost in a hundredth of a second. q, Time elapsed refers to the amount of time that has passed. r The clock is a modern day invention. s 'past' is the same as * 'to'. t There is no such time as 11:11.

Comment: But the OP's sentence doesn't work, does it? So it's not as simple as that.

Comment: @TonyK I can see your point; I shouldn't have lumped all meanings of "time" into a single unit, and considering the OP's sentence again  "time"  doesn't sound  specific enough for a modification by "such"; as you say, that is not very idiomatic. It seems that what is needed is to make this particular time specific . For instance, saying "there is no such time while your children grow up that you'll find a period of easy child rearing." does not give this impression of vagueness found in the original sentence.